# Maintain focus on input type range after mouse click to allow keyboard interaction

Tags: html, keyboard, slider

Currently I am testing out the input type "range" slider in order to put it to use in my web application.

I noticed that if I click on the slider's bar, or drag the thumb, the value will update.  However, if I then try to use the arrow keys to interact with the slider I find I'm not actually still focused on the range itself and thus the arrow keys are not interacting with the slider.

Going to a previous focusable item then tabbing to the slider, I can interact with it via the arrow keys.  But then if I decide to use the mouse I can no longer use the arrow keys after a mouse click.

I'm wondering what I'd need to do via JavaScript to maintain focus on the range to allow for keyboard interaction unless I tab away from it or the mouse clicks somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

After I posted this yesterday I later had the idea to test out the mouseup event listener.

```
HTML:
%label.{for: "#example"} Example
%input#example{type: "range", min: "0", max: "2", step: "0.1", data: {controller: "slider", action: "mouseup->slider#maintainFocus"}}

Stimulus Controller:
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
    maintainFocus() {
        this.element.focus()
    }
}
```

This worked perfectly.  So if you tab to the slider, you can interact with the keyboard.  Then if you decide you wanted to use the mouse, after dragging with the mouse or clicking on the track, focus is maintained until you either tab away or click away from it.